# PPTP VPN did not check the password

Tags: vpn, pptp, linode

I've success installed and PPTP VPN in my Linode by using this script:

https://github.com/liaohuqiu/centos-setup/blob/master/install/install_vpn.sh

```
yum install -y ppp

wget http://centos-files.liaohuqiu.net/f/pptpd-1.3.4-2.el6.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ihv pptpd-1.3.4-2.el6.x86_64.rpm
rm -rf *.rpm

rm -rf /etc/pptpd.conf
rm -rf /etc/ppp
mkdir -p /etc/ppp

echo "option /etc/ppp/options.pptpd" >> /etc/pptpd.conf
echo "localip 10.0.0.1" >> /etc/pptpd.conf
echo "remoteip 10.0.0.10-100" >> /etc/pptpd.conf

echo "ms-dns 8.8.8.8" >> /etc/ppp/options.pptpd
echo "ms-dns 8.8.4.4" >> /etc/ppp/options.pptpd

pass=`openssl rand 6 -base64`
if [ "$1" != "" ]
then pass=$1
fi
echo "vpn pptpd ${pass} *" >> /etc/ppp/chap-secrets

function config_iptables()
{
    # Reset/Flush iptables
    iptables -F
    iptables -X
    iptables -t nat -F
    iptables -t nat -X
    iptables -t mangle -F
    iptables -t mangle -X
    iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
    iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
    iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
    # Flush end

    iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

    iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE


    iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 1723 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p gre -j ACCEPT

    # Allow localhost traffic
    iptables -A INPUT -i lo   -m state --state NEW  -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo   -m state --state NEW  -j ACCEPT

    # Allow server and internal network to go anyway
    iptables -A INPUT  -s 10.0.0.0/24   -m state --state NEW  -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A OUTPUT  -m state --state NEW  -j ACCEPT

    # Allow ssh
    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport ssh -j ACCEPT

    service iptables save
    service iptables restart
}

chkconfig pptpd on
service pptpd start
config_iptables

ip=`/sbin/ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}'`
echo "===================================="
echo " VPN INSTALLATION COMPLETE"
echo "===================================="
echo " "
echo "VPN hostname/ip: ${ip}"
echo "VPN type: PPTP"
echo "VPN username: vpn"
echo "VPN password: ${pass}"
echo " "
```

It works very well. But in these days I found there are a lot off connections which make my server out of traffic.

It seems that I can connect to the server by using any account and password.

And this my config files:

```
[root@mylinode ppp]# ll
total 24
-rw------- 1 root root  16 Jun 20 01:53 chap-secrets
-rw------- 1 root root 349 Oct 23  2013 eaptls-client
-rw------- 1 root root 405 Oct 23  2013 eaptls-server
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5 Nov 16  2009 options
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  86 Jun 20 01:37 options.pptpd
-rw------- 1 root root  77 Nov 16  2009 pap-secrets
```

And the `chap-secets`

```
[root@mylinode ppp]# cat chap-secrets
vpn pptpd 111 *
```

And there the log from `/var/log/message`:

```
Jun 20 02:03:53 mylinode pptpd[23994]: CTRL: Client 221.218.36.184 control connection started
Jun 20 02:03:53 mylinode pptpd[23994]: CTRL: Starting call (launching pppd, opening GRE)
Jun 20 02:03:53 mylinode pppd[23995]: pppd 2.4.5 started by huqiu, uid 0
Jun 20 02:03:53 mylinode pppd[23995]: Using interface ppp0
Jun 20 02:03:53 mylinode pppd[23995]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/3
Jun 20 02:03:56 mylinode pppd[23995]: peer from calling number 221.218.36.184 authorized
Jun 20 02:03:57 mylinode pppd[23995]: local  IP address 10.0.0.1
Jun 20 02:03:57 mylinode pppd[23995]: remote IP address 10.0.0.10
```

I've tried to reinstall for many times, the problem is still there.

Any help will be great, I can provider more information if needed. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems you have a weak password and cracked,the man post your ip and your pass somewhere,  making your vpn server a public server,please rename your user and pass.

Comment: But I can connect to the server by using any account and any password.

Comment: You never edit /etc/ppp/options.pptpd?pptpd don't have anonymous mode,check your options.pptd--------------------------------------------refuse-pap
refuse-chap
refuse-mschap
require-mschap-v2
require-mppe-128

Answer (score 0):

You can check the contents of */etc/ppp/chap-secrets*.
The username and password that can connect to the VPN server are stored there.
The contents of the file should look like this:

```
$ cat /etc/ppp/chap-secrets
# Secrets for authentication using CHAP
# client        server  secret                  IP addresses
username1 pptpd password1 *
username2 pptpd password2 *
```

Comment: Thank you, I've added this to my `/etc/ppp/chap-secrets`, but I still can use any account and password to login in. That's weird.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [@Jarett](https://serverfault.com/users/296898/jarett)

I added this to `/etc/ppp/options.pptpd`:

```
refuse-pap
refuse-chap
refuse-mschap
require-mschap-v2
require-mppe-128
```

Then I should use the account and password in `/etc/ppp/chap-secrets` to login.

---

#### The reason

I forget to mention the content in `/etc/ppp/options.pptpd`, they were:

```
name pptpd

ms-dns 8.8.8.8
ms-dns 8.8.4.4
```

Then I connected to the server by using encryption level: `None`.